# Why I get permission denied when trying to read ROM from a device in sysfs?

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, firmware, rom, sysfs

reading the docs for sysfs on https://mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs-pci.txt

> The 'rom' file is special in that it provides read-only access to the device's
> ROM file, if available.  It's disabled by default, however, so applications
> should write the string "1" to the file to enable it before attempting a read
> call, and disable it following the access by writing "0" to the file.  Note
> that the device must be enabled for a rom read to return data successfully.
> In the event a driver is not bound to the device, it can be enabled using the
> 'enable' file, documented above.

i'm trying to figure out which firmware/microcode version i'm running. The specific device is a GPU included in an APU package.

```
$ lspci
...
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt [Radeon 680M] (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
...
$ cd /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.0
$ pwd -P
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.0
$ cat vbios_version
113-REMBRANDT-X37
$ cat enable
1
$ echo 1 > enable
bash: echo: write error: Device or resource busy
$ cat enable
1
$ cat rom
cat: rom: No such file or directory
$ echo 1 > rom
bash: rom: Permission denied
$ id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Comment: `echo 1 > enabled` should be `echo 1 > enable`.

Comment: my bad. fixing the question... in my command history it is actually correct `enable` :+1  Using wrong `enabled` gives me permission denied btw, in case this is a hint to something.

Comment: You are probably in the wrong directory since `0000:00:03.0` does not match `03:00.0`. There is probably no "rom" file in "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0". Try the "/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.0" directory.

Comment: my bad again, i'm typing this for another machine instead of copy pasting... you are again correct on the mismatch. but again, it was my mistake pasting here. the paths are correct, same outcome). i will edit again to correct this and make sure there are no more mistakes :(

Comment: Could you post the output from `lspci -v -s 03:00.0`? There should be a line that starts with `Expansion ROM at` if it has a ROM resource.

Comment: thanks. No mention of ROM anywhere there. This might explain why sysfs doesn't have anything. Will have to start looking at the driver i am afraid

Comment: I suggest looking at `amdgpu_get_bios()` in "drivers/gpu/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_bios.c", and looking for a "Fetched VBIOS from " message or an "Unable to locate a BIOS ROM" message in the kernel log.